# How to replace part of a function call with variable in Python?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with some function expressions as values. Each of the values are very similar, except the part in the middle. In the following example, only `earn_yld`, `free_cash_flow_yield` and `eps_growth` are different in the long formula.

```
factor_bql = {
    "ltm_earnings_yield": bq.func.dropna(bq.data.earn_yld(as_of_date=bq.func.RANGE(params['start'],params['end']))),
    "ltm_fcf_yield": bq.func.dropna(bq.data.free_cash_flow_yield(as_of_date=bq.func.RANGE(params['start'],params['end']))),
    'ltm_eps_growth': bq.func.dropna(bq.data.eps_growth(as_of_date=bq.func.RANGE(params['start'],params['end'])))
}
```

Is there any way to write a function or variable to simplify the values of the dictionary to something like

```
def simple_formula(xyz):
    ... ...

factor_bql = {
    "ltm_earnings_yield": simple_formula('earn_yld'),
    "ltm_fcf_yield": simple_formula('free_cash_flow_yield'),
    'ltm_eps_growth': simple_formula('eps_growth')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this in following way:

```py
def simple_formula(fn):
    return bq.func.dropna(fn(as_of_date=bq.func.RANGE(params['start'],params['end'])))

factor_bql = {
    "ltm_earnings_yield": simple_formula(bq.data.earn_yld),
    "ltm_fcf_yield": simple_formula(bq.data.free_cash_flow_yield),
    'ltm_eps_growth': simple_formula(bq.data.eps_growth)
}
```

So, functions themselves (not their names) are parameters of `simple_formula`.

Comment: @Tupteq--I suppose argument xyz is superfluous in simpe_formula?

Comment: @DarrylG I assumed `xyz` to represent an example parameter (as in question). But I think you're right, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bq.data is some object:

```
def simple_formula(xyz):
    method = getattr(bq.data, xyx) # get a method by its name
    return bq.func.dropna(method(as_of_date=bq.func.RANGE(params['start'],params['end'])))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that approach and got the following error message:
```
  File "<ipython-input-32-40f549057bae>", line 20
    return bq.func.dropna(method((as_of_date=bq.func.RANGE(params['start'],params['end'])))
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```
Looks like that the equal sign in the formula is generating syntax error. That is not the issue if I directly use the formula, rather than simple_formula function.

Comment: Looks like brackets don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `globals` function to call a function in the current module by the string representation of its name.

```py
def func1(bar):
    return "func1" + str(bar)


def func2(bar):
    return "func2" + str(bar)


def simple_formula(func_name):
    return globals()[func_name](bar="baz")


factor_bql = {
    "key1": simple_formula("func1"),
    "key2": simple_formula("func2"),
}

print(factor_bql["key2"]) # prints "func2baz"
```